# How to show my json response events in fullcalendar view or how to load events from function(json feed) to fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Actually Im trying to show events(json feed) on fullcalendar. How to show my json response events in fullcalendar view.

heres my controller codes:

```
public ActionResult GetEventWithSpecifiedDate(string start, string end)
        {
            var newEvent = new List<CalendarEventModel>();

            newEvent.Add(new CalendarEventModel(){
                id = 1,
                start = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),
                end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),
                title = " it works",
            });
            newEvent.Add(new CalendarEventModel(){
                id = 2,
                start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ffff"),
                end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ffff"),
                title = "really it works!",
            });
            return Json(new JsonResultModel() { success = true, aaData = newEvent }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

---

and heres my js code:

```
 genericCalendar: function (id, ajaxSourceUrl, data, eventDataTransform, callbackFnc) {
        $(id).fullCalendar('destroy');
        $(id).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            allDayDefault: false,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            ignoreTimezone: false,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                if (callbackFnc)
                    callbackFnc();
                $(id).fullCalendar('refetchResources');
            },
            editable: true,
            monthNames: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'],
            monthNamesShort: ["Ocak", "Şub", "Mar", "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem", "Ağu", "Eyl", "Ekim", "Kas", "Ara"],
            dayNames: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Pzr", "Pts", "Sal", "Çrş", "Prş", "Cum", "Cts"],
            titleFormat: { month: "MMMM yyyy", week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", day: " d MMM yyyy , dddd" },
            eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
                if (eventDataTransform)
                    eventDataTransform(eventData);
                return eventData;
            },
            events: function (start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxSourceUrl,
                    data: {
                        start: start.toLocaleDateString(),
                        end: end.toLocaleDateString()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                      var events = [];
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                            debugger;
                            events.push({
                                id: value['id'],
                                title: value['title'],
                                start: value['start'],
                                end: value['end']
                            });
                        });
                        console.log(index + ": " + value);
                    }
                });
            },

            eventRender: function (calEvent, $event) {
                calEvent.type //this is my new field
            },
            eventClick: function (event, element) {
                if (callbackFnc)
                    callbackFnc(event, element);
                $(id).fullCalendar('refetchResources');
            }
        });
    },
```

How to show my json response events in fullcalendar view.. I cannot..

Comment: I think your'e looking for [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) and/or [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Comment: thankss for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly.

As stated in the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

> **gotoDate**
>
> Moves the calendar to an arbitrary date.
>
> `.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )`
>
> `date` can be a Moment object, or anything the Moment constructor
>   accepts.